# How to make Moq understand that the type constraint is acceptable for the Verified call?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, moq

> **Summary**

I'm currently writing some integration code so that I can interact with an accounting system.

The accounting system in question is Acceo Acomba, using its SDK which turns to be distributed COM objects.

I have written a generic class that serves the purpose of a generic repository for any given Acomba entity.

```
public abstract class AcombaRepository<TEntity, TNativeRepository>
    where TEntity : class
    where TNativeRepository : IBaseDataKey {
    public AcombaRepository( TNativeRepository nativeRepository, IMapper entityMapper ) {
        // Guard clauses...
        NativeRepository = nativeRepository;
        this.entityMapper = entityMapper;
    }

    protected readonly TNativeRepository NativeRepository;

    public TEntity Create( TEntity toCreate ) {
        NativeRepository.ReserveCardNumber(); // Insert
        entityMapper.Map( toCreate, NativeRepository ); // Assigning props 
        NativeRepository.AddCard(); // Save or commit to Acomba
    }
}
```

**IBaseDataKey**

This interface is the base entity for any given accessible entity within the system. In order to make sure I have access to its basics, I put this type constraint on my generic repository.

**AcombaProductsRepository**

This is the code under test which actually use the base method as-is.

```
public class AcombaProductsRepository : AcombaRepository<MyProduct, IProduct022> {
    public AcombaPRoductsRepository( IProduct022 nativeRepository, IMapper productMapper ) 
        : base( nativeRepository, productMapper ) { 
    }
}
```

> **Unit Testing**

In order to make sure that my code uses the Acomba SDK adequately to create a new entity within the Acomba underlying data store, I verify that certain steps are strictly respected.

```
public class AcombaProductsRepositoryTests {
    private readonly Mock<IProduct022> nativeRepositoryMock;
    private readonly AcombaProductsRepsoitory sut;

    public AcombaProductsRepositoryTests() {
        nativeRepositoryMock = new Mock<IProduct022>();
        sut = new AcombaProductsRepository( nativeRepositoryMock.Object );
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Create_Should_Reserve_A_Card_Number() {
        var toCreate = new MyProduct();
        nativeRepositoryMock.Setup( r => r.ReserveCardNumber() ).Verifiable();

        sut.Create( toCreate );

        nativeRepositoryMock.Verify( r => r.ReserveCardNumber() );
    }
}
```

Here, although the interface `IProduct022` derives from `IBaseDataKey`, Moq states that the expected invocation

- **`IProduct022.ReserveCardNumber`**

was never performed. Besides, it also states that the performed invocation was

- **`IBaseDataKey.ReserveCardNumber`**

For the essence of the unit test itself, it doesn't actually matter whether the performed invocation was either, as long as the `ReserveCardNumber` is called upon.

> **How to make this test pass?**

---

> **Further Details (edit)**

Here's the error message from the test result.
[image: Test Result Error Message]

As I take it, Moq performs the invocation of the base `IBaseDataKey` class instead of the `IProduct022` derived one because of the type constraint, I suspect.

Comment: provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. There is not enough details at the moment

Comment: Also if `nativeRepositoryMock.Setup()` is already `.Verifiable()` then all that is needed during assert is `nativeRepositoryMock.Verify();` all setups that are verifiable will be verified.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for your feedback. I knew about the `.Verify()` thing, except that I want to specifically verify this very call since I'm unit testing. I figured out that because I setup my mock for different method calls throughout my tests, I needed to check whether only this very call was performed.

Comment: Show the code under test so that is can be used to reproduce the problem. We can't provide much help if we can't run the same code and get the same problem. That way we can try to find a cause and solution. Again a [mcve] is needed otherwise this question is just going to remain off-topic.

Comment: @Nkosi edited the code under test within the base AcombaRepository and the derived repository to access the product entities.

Comment: I've just complete a recreation of the unit test based on the minimal example provided and the test passed as expected with no errors. The example provided is incomplete as assumptions were made concerning interfaces and entities used. The test ultimately passed which indicates that the error is unable to be reproduced based on the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

The following minimal example was used based on the provided OP

```
public class AcombaProductsRepository : AcombaRepository<MyProduct, IProduct022> {
    public AcombaProductsRepository(IProduct022 nativeRepository)
        : base(nativeRepository) {
    }
}

public abstract class AcombaRepository<TEntity, TNativeRepository>
    where TEntity : class
    where TNativeRepository : IBaseDataKey {

    public AcombaRepository(TNativeRepository nativeRepository) {
        NativeRepository = nativeRepository;
    }

    protected readonly TNativeRepository NativeRepository;

    public TEntity Create(TEntity toCreate) {
        NativeRepository.ReserveCardNumber(); // Insert
        NativeRepository.AddCard(); // Save or commit to Acomba
        return toCreate;
    }
}
```

The following minimal assumptions were made of the interface and entities used as they were not provided in the OP

```
public interface IBaseDataKey {
    void ReserveCardNumber();
    void AddCard();
}

public interface IProduct022 : IBaseDataKey {

}

public class MyProduct {

}
```

The following Test was exercised based on the information provided in the OP and using MSTest and the latest version of Moq

```
[TestClass]
public class AcombaProductsRepositoryTests {
    private readonly Mock<IProduct022> nativeRepositoryMock;
    private readonly AcombaProductsRepository sut;

    public AcombaProductsRepositoryTests() {
        nativeRepositoryMock = new Mock<IProduct022>();
        sut = new AcombaProductsRepository(nativeRepositoryMock.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void _Create_Should_Reserve_A_Card_Number() {
        //Arrange
        var toCreate = new MyProduct();
        nativeRepositoryMock.Setup(r => r.ReserveCardNumber()).Verifiable();

        //Act
        sut.Create(toCreate);

        //Asert
        nativeRepositoryMock.Verify(r => r.ReserveCardNumber());
    }
}
```

The test when exercised passed without exception.

I suggest a review of original code as issue as currently presented is not reproducible.